# check if element indexes are inside 2d array (for moving by one in any direction)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have this two dimensional array of objects

```
private Cell[,] mapCells = new Cell[10, 10];
```

and I want to check if a key value pair with the coordinates **x = m** and **y = n** exists in my array.

I go for this

```
        bool cellExists = index.x >= 0 && // check left
              index.y >= 0 && // check bottom
              index.x < mapCells.GetLength(0) && // check right
              index.y < mapCells.GetLength(1); // check top
```

So with this bool I check if the cell would be on the map or outside.

Is there a more elegant way to check this?

---

**EDIT:**

When checking this I get a movement direction like

```
  Vector2 dir = new Vector2(/* this can be
     (0,1) // up
     (0,-1) // down
     (-1,0) // left
     (1,0) // right
  */);
```

So I know which direction is given.

When I move right I don't need to check the left side I think.

Comment: I think, it's good enough

Comment: How do you define *more elegant*? It´s fairly opinion-based, isn´t it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I think he means shorter or faster. I see not much possibilities in either direction.

Comment: I edited my question maybe the new information will help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a review asking for improvement to working code and thus should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @peterHasemann: That's an entirely different question now. Hmm....

Comment: should I delete the question and ask it on codereview?#

Comment: I'd expect using sentinel values around the border instead of range check... like `if (mapCells[newX, newY] == sentinel) { /*move is invalid*/ }`...

Comment: To me question looks fine for SO, probably ok on CR too. Likely to get different type of suggestions so.

Comment: I created a post https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185753/check-if-an-element-exists-in-a-two-dimensional-array vote to close this question here if you want

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could hide it behind the extension method to make it looks more elegant.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsExist(this Cell[,] mapCells, Cell index)
    {
        bool cellExists = index.x >= 0 &&
               index.y >= 0 &&
               index.x < mapCells.GetLength(0) &&
               index.y < mapCells.GetLength(1);

        return cellExists;
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
mapCells.IsExist(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no other way to test this. The only optimization I can think of would be to cache the size, but you're not gaining much there.

Comment: I edited my question maybe the new information will help

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "elegant". You could do this (off the top of my head):

```
bool cellExists = Math.Min(mapCells.GetLength(0) - 1, Math.Abs(x)) == x 
                && Math.Min(mapCells.GetLength(1) - 1, Math.Abs(y)) == y
```

The idea is to first getting the absolute value of x or y, and then check if the minimum of that and the axis upper value results in x or y. If it does, you're good.

It's shorter, but readability is questionable. And I doubt it is any faster than your original solution.